# How to generate OTP codes offline by Security Key in Debian?

Tags: yubikey, fido-u2f, otp

Assume you need the OTPs by devices which are separate from the Debian system which generates the codes. Here, the U2F does not work in all cases so I need OTPs. 
I am trying to add offline OTP functionality by YubiKey Neo in Debian. 
My idea:

1. have some key server on your Linux
2. some frontend to generate OTPs.

I have not found any GUI/UI frontend for the generation of OTPs by `apt search ...`. 
Things already installed and partially tested

```
apt search YubiHSM

sudo apt install yubikey-val
sudo apt install python-serial python-crypto
sudo apt install yhsm-tools yhsm-yubikey-ksm yhsm-validation-server yhsm-daemon
```

I added `username:keyID` in `$HOME/.yubico/authorized_yubikeys`.
I did not manage to set up any server system in `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`. 
Rejected OTP types

1. [Celada] time-based OTPs (TOPT) because no clock in YubiKey
2. Ticket #00019568: Their answer says that it is not possible in the following.

   > This is not supported by the YubiKey. If you are looking to ask for a new feature request, that is best done at our forum in the Suggestions section (https://forum.yubico.com/viewforum.php?f=12&sid=6d5c3368d99340d20ef691f2146c44c7).

OS: Debian 8.7
Fido U2F: Yubico YubiKey Neo, YubiKey 4 White
Yubico ticket for sequence-based OTPs: #00019568 *I want to genarate OTPs by YubiKey Neo. The following thread proposes that OTP should be sequence-based OTPs. How can you genarate such OTPs by YubiKey Neo in Linux Debian 8.7?*
Yubico forum thread: [How can you genarate OTPs offline by YubiKey in Debian?](https://forum.yubico.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=2625)

Comment: Instead of using OTPs, you might do better to just use U2F, since your Yubikey token supports it. Then you can just use `pam_u2f` and call it a day.

Comment: I guess maybe I'm having trouble understanding your use case. "Debian system which generates the codes" sounds odd. Usually the point is that a token generates the OTPs. Are you looking at OTP standards, like HOTP and TOTP?

Comment: TOTP requires a clock. Yubikeys don't have clocks.

Comment: You can't, because it wouldn't be secure. How could the Yubikey trust that it is not being fed a fake clock signal?

Comment: If you want to use a token that doesn't have a clock then you can't have a time-based OTP. You have to use a sequence-based OTP.

Comment: @Gilles Yubico support says that a sequence-based OTP is not supported in Linux Debian. I tried to complete unsuccessfully their next proposed step, please see the body. - - Do you have other proposals?